# Teradata 3706 Error when using TD_WEEK_OF_CALENDAR

Tags: sql, teradata

I took a query of mine that was at the daily level and tried to convert it to weekly using the function TD_WEEK_OF_CALENDAR and it seems to make all sorts of things stop working and I can't quite make sense of it. Here is a basic example, note I have changed the query so it might seem like a strange query to run but it shows where the error occurs easy enough.

The error I get says, "Query Failed. 3706: Syntax error: expected something between ',' and the 'year' keyword." However, the subquery runs just fine and if I remove that join the query runs just fine so I am a bit stumped.

```
select a.Customer
    , TD_WEEK_OF_CALENDAR(ab.DateField) as Week
    , z.AvgYearBalance
    , avg(ab.Balance) as WeeklyBalance
from Customer a
left join Balances ab on a.Customer=ab.Customer

left join(
     select a.Customer
         , year(ab.DateField) as Year
         , avg(ab.Balance) as AvgYearBalance
     from Customer a
     left join Balances ab on a.Customer=ab.Customer
     group by 1,2
) z on a.Customer=z.Customer

group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` is not a builtin function in Teradata. Only older ODBC drivers had a switch to automatically translate it into valid syntax, but this was deprectaed since TD14 and removed in TD16. It only worked for plain Selects, not in Views, etc., apparently it's also not supported in Derived Tables. Simply switch to valid Teradata & Stanadard SQL:

```
extract(year from ab.DateField) as "Year"
```

Btw, the latest "Feature Upgrade 1" of TD16.20 reintroduced those functions like UCASE, CONCAT, YEAR independently of the connection :-)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. What a strange thing, I use year in so many queries and never had an issue until introducing the week function I mentioned above.

Comment: Btw, if you actually perform the same joins twice to get different aggregation levels, you can probably replace it with an OLAP-function...